# HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync giving 500 error - how can I get more detailed message?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

I have a HttpClient making a request for a file (from sharepoint, though I don't know if that's relevant). It's working well when called from one area of the application but fails when called from a different area, and I'm trying to debug why this is. However, I get the following error which is quite vague:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).`

This is thrown by `client.GetByteArrayAsync` (code below) - is it possible to get a more detailed error message from this?

```cs
private async Task<byte[]> RequestBlobData(string url)
{
    var myCache = GetCredentialCache(url);

    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = myCache }))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringResponseBody", "true");

        return await client.GetByteArrayAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}
```

(Just to be clear, I'm not expecting someone to be able to fix the actual error, I'm hoping that someone will know how I can get a more detailed error message.)

Comment: Hey could you resolve this?

Comment: I don't remember to be honest. I don't have any code changes in this method since I asked the question, so it's quite possible that I never got a useful error message and just had to work by trial and error. Sorry I can't help more!